# End tag for element "HEAD" which is not open, XHTML vs. HTML, Docttype 1.0 vs Doctype 4.01

Tags: html, validation, doctype, section508

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to fix some issues and I am stumped on this one. I am getting a validation error for "End tag for element "HEAD" which is not open" However looking at my code, I am not seeing where it could be. I know this website used to have some XHTML elements, but I have removed those elements. I was hoping to get another set of eyes on this. If it helps, the DOCTYPE was 1.0 but I was getting alot of issues from that as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <title>Radio Directory</title>
        <meta name="author"  content="Joe Blow"> 
        <meta name="email"   content="Joe@MyEmail.com">
        <meta name="description" content="The Radio Directory">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache,no-store">
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">

        <script type="text/javascript">
        if (self != top)
          top.location = self.location;
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        if (top.frames.length!=0)
          top.location=self.document.location;
        </script>

        <style type="text/css" media="all">
            @import url("style/main.css");
        </style>
        <link href="style/tablecloth.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tablecloth/tablecloth.js"></script>
        </head>
```

Comment: Hm, strange. The exact sample you've provided passes HTML 4.01 Transitional validation on Validator.nu, and on validator.w3.org with the addition of a <body> tag (I have no idea why it is needed there). There might be some junk characters somewhere in your source markup that are not present in the sample you've provided.

Comment: Who's validator are you using? (Also: Why the section508 tag?)

Comment: I am required to use SortSite and Because Section 508 is the short term that describes making websites for those with handicaps. That way theres equal opportunities for everyone to use it equally. Its not too bad, it points out ways to use Best Practices, but otherwise its very nit picky on smaller insignificant things.